# Crash in Windows Store app after returning to start page

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

First, the flow:

My app loads splash screen to start page (login).

From login screen, load to home page.

From home page, load to second page.

From second back hit "Back" button, calls "GoBack" To Home Page

From Home page hit "Back", calls "GoBack" to login screen.

*Crash*

Exception info:
Exception: {"No installed components were detected. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800F1000)"}
Message: "Cannot resolve TargetName TextLabel."

Note: If I don't go to the second screen and just go directly back from the home screen, there is no crash and app runs fine.

It may possibly have to do with a style somewhere, but I can't seem to find where. The error info doesn't seem to want to give me any hints either.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had made a custom AppBar button style and hadn't removed animations that reference things that don't exist anymore. I don't know why it only crashed with that specific flow, but that ended up being it.